# laravel a href return page 404 not found

Tags: php, laravel

i have this a href in my code to navigate to another

```
  <a href="deleteValue/{{$user->value_id}}" 
                                        onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this Value?')"
                                        class="btn btn-danger btn-fab btn-fab-mini btn-round" role="button" aria-disabled="true">
                                         <i class="material-icons">close</i></a>
```

the page i redirect to return 404 not found ..this is the url

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/currentpage/deleteValue/72
```

why is the url look like this ? it must look like
`http://127.0.0.1:8000/deleteValue/72`

Comment: Try to add a leading slash in your href like so: “/deleteValue…”

Answer (score 2):

Add a slash at the beginning to be absolute to the host.

```
href="/deleteValue/{{$user->value_id}}"
```

Comment: Don't forget to [mark the answer as accepted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).